# In Raymer diagram “Take off parameter- Take off distance”, what is the difference among “balanced field length”, “over 50 ft”, “ground roll”?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, aircraft-design

Raymer in his book Suggests a method to find Wing Loading W/S (for example we consider jet with 2 engines) (starting from specific thrust T/W, CLto, density/reference density etc.). In step 1: he suggests to use graphichs "Fig. 5.4 Takeoff distance estimation": you enter takeoff distance (in ordinate), so .. in abscissa you can determine Takeoff Parameter ("TOP") Step 2: From "TOP" you can find (W/S)=(TOP)sigmaCLto*(t/W) The questions are : in figure 5.4 you can find many diagrams: takeoff distance for a) "Balanced field Length" b) "over 50 ft" c) "ground roll". Which one I have to use? What is the difference among them? Which curve you have to use, in order to calculate "take off parameter"?

Source: Daniel P. Raymer, Aircraft design: a conceptual approach. Chapter 5 Thrust-to-weight ratio and wing loading, paragraph 5.3 Wing Loading, sub-paragraph Takeoff Distance, page 88-89 and "Fig. 5.4 Takeoff distance estimation".